Independence assumptions in correlations when all data comes from same individual
This feels like a silly question, but anyhow - do the independence assumptions in common correlation tests matter much if all the data comes from the same individual and I don't want to make any broader inferences / assumptions?
For example: lets say I was interested in knowing if, for a specific cricket player, their maximal running velocity in the run up was correlated with the speed of the ball bowled and I got data from 1000 balls - could I treat the balls as independent for the purposes of a correlation analysis even though they all come from the same player? I am only interested in knowing this relationship for the player in question, and not making inferences about any broader population.

Welcome to crossvalidated! I think you can improve this question (and the likelihood of getting useful answers) if you can provide more information about your dataset. What variables are being measured? What exactly do you hope to accomplish with your analysis?

Thanks! I have edited with a (hopefully more clear) example of what I'm getting at. I guess I'm trying to get an idea of how to go about determining an effect size for a correlation type analysis when I want to understand relationships within individuals

Yes, you can. It may be helpful to think about the population as the set of all possible pairs $(X_i, Y_i)$ that could have been (or ever will be) generated. So the fact that the data "only comes from one individual" doesn't really matter here.
Here's another way to look at it: Suppose that $(X_i, Y_i)$ a bivariate normal with parameters $\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma_x, \sigma_y$, and $\rho$. Does observing the value of $(X_1, Y_1)$ give us any information about $(X_2, Y_2)$, that we don't already get from the parameters? Obviously not.
If you have extra information, such as the time of the game that the observation comes from or if you have data from multiple players, then it can become more nuanced. In these cases, it is possible that observing one pair $(X_i, Y_i)$ can give you additional information about another pair, beyond what is captured by the bivariate normal parameters. You would address this scenario by using a more sophisticated model (e.g., regression).
